# WAMP, getting undefined index on $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]

Tags: php, url-rewriting, aptana, wamp, xdebug

I am debugging with xdebug and Aptana, when xdebug reaches this:

```
 if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
  $url = $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 } else {
  $url = $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 }
```

I get :

```
Error: [8] Undefined index: SERVER_PORT
```

is this some configuration issue in WAMP? Or does the issue lie in xdebug?

Comment: Gotta ask: Are you running this via a web server?

Comment: The code works on a web server, but when I'm debugging with Aptana, the code fails

Comment: So then the answer is likely no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not something that Xdebug causes, but your PHP install. PHP is bascially telling you that the $_SERVER variable doesn't exist. And as comments already said, that is because you are not running in a webserver environment. You need to debug through your web server in order for this to work - but I'm not sure if Aptana can do that.